# Is there a way to read browser cookies on redirecting URL from Spring Controller

Tags: spring-boot, cookies

I want to read the cookies when i hit / which will redirect to some  url , Below is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")

public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    
    response.sendRedirect("https://www.somelocation.com"); // after redirect browser will have cookies
    
}
```

Is there a way in controller i can read the browser cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can read cookie using `@CookieValue` annotation.

Eg:

```
@GetMapping("cookie")
    public Map<String, Boolean> hasCookie(@CookieValue(name = "user-session", required = false) String userSession) {
        return Map.of("user-session", StringUtils.hasText(userSession));
    }
```

curl to test

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8081/data/cookie?user-session=128162172681' \
--header 'Cookie: user-session=hello-cookie'
```

Yout will get true/false response user-session when called with header and without header

```json
{"user-session":true}
```